# Devel dsm() function in Drupal 8 page.html.twig

Tags: 8, debugging, theming

Is Devel module's dsm() function available in page.html.twig? If it is not available, is there a way to make it available?

I am able to use dsm() in .theme file but not in page.html.twig.

I am aware of dump() function in .twig. dump() is similar to var_dump() of php and the output is not as clean as Devel module's dsm() function.

Using dsm() or dpr() in page.html.twig causes error and site does not load.

Comment: I don't personally know the answer to your question, but have a look here: https://drupal.org/node/1805526

Comment: @Sifro I am aware of dump() function but it is not very clean.

Comment: Yeah I know, but comment #4 says "You can also use kpr, dpr, dsm, etc. if devel module for D8 is downloaded and enabled. psynaptic took care of that"

Haven't verified it though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just do it in `hook_preprocess_page()` instead.

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  dpm($variables);
}
```

Comment: As per your suggestion, in the absence of dpm() and dsm() in page.html.twig I used it in my theme's .theme file inside                       function hook_preprocess_page(&$variables) { dsm($variables);}

Comment: The only problem with this approach is if you are debugging a view template or block template. I guess you could use their respective hooks. But I think the better way of doing it is using @Cottser's approach.

Answer (score 6):

The Kint submodule in [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) 8.x now provides [Kint](http://raveren.github.io/kint/) debugging functionality in Twig templates.

```
{{ kint() }}
{{ kint(variable_one, variable_two) }}
```

Enjoy! Screenshots and a bit more info here: https://drupal.org/node/2218949

And I want to add that I hope the contrib space in 8.x ends up with tons of debugging options, for example I'm looking forward to seeing [Ladybug](https://github.com/raulfraile/Ladybug) implemented!

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how is Ladybug better, why would it be your choice over Kint?

Comment: Kint is fantastic, and I was happy to spend time working on the Kint/Twig integration for the Devel Drupal 8 module :) I never said Ladybug was better, I just think it's always nice to have more options!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the kind words and putting up with Kint's terrible means of integration :)

Answer (score 1):

Use twig method for debugging. first go to sites/default/services.yml

and set debug:true

then you can use twig method for debugging.

{{ dump(attributes) }}