# Logo is not displaying

Tags: theming, 8

This is the code I used in Drupal 7.

```
            <a href="<?php print $base_path ?>" title="<?php print t('Home') ?>">
                <img src="<?php print $logo ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home') ?>" />
            </a>
```

This is the code I am using for Drupal 8.

```
           <a href="{{ base_path }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}">      
    <span>{{ logopath }}</span>
                <img src="{{logo}}" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}" alt="T.M. Patel International School"/>
            </a>
```

If I upload the logo, it doesn't display. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

This Link might be helpful :  http://www.lohmeyer.rocks/blog/2015/01/14/00187-print-your-themes-logo-path-drupal-8-twig.

I think you should define the logo path variable first into `template.tpl` in `MyTheme_preprocess_page` function.

One More thing you are trying to use `{{logopath}}` in 'span' tag and into 'src' its `{{logo}}`.

Comment: i tried it..its nt working...

Comment: There isn't any template.tpl, in Drupal 8.

Comment: @kiamlaluno thanks, i thinks its Mytheme.theme file instaead of tempalte.tpl, if i am wrong kindly make a correction.

Comment: The main file of a theme has .theme extension, now, if you are referring to that. In Drupal 7, it was template.php, though, not template.tpl.

Comment: @Swati Try debugging your variables. These links might be helpful to debug twig files https://drupalize.me/blog/201405/lets-debug-twig-drupal-8 and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98014/devel-dsm-function-in-drupal-8-page-html-twig

Comment: i tried all these methods but still not getting it.